# How to reduce log file size of MS SQL database

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, logfile

How to reduce log file size of MS SQL database. The requirement is to reduce log file of the version control server's DB, Shrinking is not an option in our case.

Comment: Why shrinking is not an option for you?

Comment: We have shrink the DB logs already, but it doesn't create much space. Total size of Logs is 30 GB and after shrinking, it's not creates space more than 500 MB.

Comment: No, I haven't found any other alternative to answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to reduce log file size of MS SQL database

Shrinking is the only option here, but you need to clear out the log by backing it up first. Otherwise, there won't be any free space to shrink. After you shrink it once, you can keep it from getting blown out by either

- Backing up your transaction logs more regularly. How often depends on your RPO
- Setting the database to Simple Mode. This is only suggested if your RPO is large enough to where your FULL BACKUPs and DIFFERENTIALS would cover it.

Comment: What do you mean by RPO and RTO exactly?

Comment: Paul Ranal has a [good blog explaing this](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-6-of-30-backups-understanding-rto-and-rpo/) @TT and for this case, RPO only matters